# getting position of input string then get substring on both ends

Tags: c#, string, truncate

I have a search function that searches keywords in a block of text and displays a truncated version of the results. My problem is that it will not show the searched keyword if its near the end.

For example.

Text = "A block of text is text that is grouped together in some way, such as with the use of paragraphs or blockquotes on a Web page. Often times, the text takes on the shape of a square or rectangular block"

I search for "times" with

```
 text = text.Substring(0, 100) + "...";
```

It will return

```
"A block of text is text that is grouped together in some way, such as with the use of paragraphs or..."
```

Is there a way to return 100 characters before and after the searched keyword?

Comment: To set last 100 characters: `text.Substring(text.Length - 100, 100)`. `text.Substring(0, 100)` is correct for returning first 100 ones.

Comment: that would work for some cases. However what if the block of text is 500 characters long and the searched keyword is in the middle at position 100? 
This wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to truncate words even if the word passed 100 character limit, I suggest you using `StringBuilder` & `Split` by whitespace together with keyword search: http://joelabrahamsson.com/c-method-for-cropping-text-without-breaking-words/.

Comment: @KevinC why did you remove the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       string s = "A block of text is text that is grouped together in some way, such as with the use of paragraphs or";
       string wordtoSearch = "block";
       int firstfound = s.IndexOf(wordtoSearch);

        // If the index of the first letter found is greater than 100, get the 100 letters before the found word and 100 letters after the found word
        if (firstfound > 100)
        {
            string before = s.Substring(firstfound , firstfound-100);
            string after = s.Substring(firstfound + wordtoSearch.Length, 100);
            Console.WriteLine(before);
            Console.WriteLine(after);
        }
    //// If the index of the first letter found is less than 100, get the letters before the found word and 100 letters after the found word 
        if(firstfound < 100)
        {
            string before = s.Substring(0, firstfound);
            Console.WriteLine(before);
            if(s.Length >100)
            {
            string after = s.Substring(firstfound + wordtoSearch.Length, 100);
            Console.WriteLine(after);
            }
            else
            {
                string after = s.Substring(firstfound + wordtoSearch.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(after);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work for me. I did modify the code abit
 -----  before = s.Substring(firstfound - 99, firstfound - (firstfound - 99));

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
    string s = "A block of text is text that is grouped together in some way, such as with the use of paragraphs or";
    string toBeSearched = "grouped";
    int firstfound = s.IndexOf(toBeSearched);       
    if (firstfound != -1 )
    {
        string before = s.Substring(0 , firstfound);
        string after = s.Substring(firstfound + toBeSearched.Length);         
    }
```

**[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uhoxal)**

Comment: To make it slightly more generic, replace the '0' with: Math.Max(0, firstfound - 100)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as well, making it a bit more reusable and able to match multiple instances of the keyword

```
string input = "A block of text is text that is grouped together in some way, such as with the use of paragraphs or blockquotes on a Web page. Often times, the text takes on the shape of a square or rectangular block";
int buffer = 30; // how much do you want to show before/after
string match = "times";

int location = input.IndexOf(match);
while (location != -1) {
    // take buffer before and after:
    int start = location - Math.Min (buffer , location); // don't take before start
    int end = location + match.Length 
            + Math.Min( buffer,  input.Length - location - match.Length); // don't take after end
    Console.WriteLine("..." + input.Substring(start, end-start) + "...");
    location = input.IndexOf(match,location+1);
}
```

Giving you an output of

```
...A block of text is text that is gro...
...with the use of paragraphs or blockquotes on a Web page. Often ...
...pe of a square or rectangular block...
```